# Filter MongoDB using Express and a custom URL with SQL LIKE operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How to make an SQL LIKE Operator with "express": "^4.15.3" and "mongodb": "^2.2.30" using an URL to pass the parameter? Backend looks like this.

```
app.get('/api/issues', (req, res) => {
const filter = {};
if (req.query.transaction) filter.transaction = req.query.transaction;

db.collection('issues').find(filter).toArray()
    .then((issues) => {
      res.json({
        records: issues,
      });
    });
};
```

The URL looks like this.
http://localhost:3000/api/issues?transaction=/match/

In SQL it would be: http://localhost:3000/api/issues?transaction=%match%

When querying for an exact item it works: http://localhost:3000/api/issues?transaction=someItem

The following wont work:

http://localhost:3000/api/issues?transaction=/match/

http://localhost:3000/api/issues?transaction=.*match. *

When hardcoding the value it returns all entries as expected.

```
db.collection('issues').find({transaction: /match/}).toArray() ...
```

I traced the problem down to quotation marks beeing inserted. So instead of /match/ the find() method receives "/match/".A String.replace('"', '') didn't solve the problem so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Because it's a "string" and not a "regular expression" which is what you are "hardcoding". So simply either use [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) which allows an input argument that is just a "string" or use [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to build a build a regular expression pattern from a "string".

Comment: Doesn't work with $regex but worked with RegExp() like so: const regex = new RegExp(`^${req.query.transaction}`); +1